# What I do to enhance this statement select into because it take too much time for 2000 rows?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, indexing, sql-execution-plan

I work on SQL Server I have slow transfer data when make select into table, it takes too much time to transfer small number (2000) of rows

This is my execution plan:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1o3p8NOt

And this is my query:

```
SELECT  
    d.PartID ,
    d.Code ,
    d.CodeTypeID ,
    tr.RevisionID ,
    tr.ZPLID,
    tr.partlevel,
    d.FeatureName,
    d.FeatureValue
INTO 
    ExtractReports.dbo.TEqualCodes
FROM
    ExtractReports.dbo.TAllData d WITH(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN
    parts.tradecodes tr WITH(NOLOCK) ON d.partid = tr.partid 
                                     AND d.codetypeid = tr.codetypeid 
                                     AND tr.partlevel = 0 
                                     AND d.code = tr.code 
                                     AND tr.zplid = 4239
LEFT JOIN
    [ExtractReports].[dbo].[TradeCodesInsert] i WITH(NOLOCK) ON i.partid = tr.partid 
                                                             AND i.codetypeid = tr.codetypeid 
                                                             AND i.partlevel = tr.partlevel 
                                                             AND i.partlevel = 0 
                                                             AND tr.zplid = i.zplid
WHERE
    i.partid IS NULL
```

Table structure of two tables trade codes and trade codes insert

```
CREATE TABLE [Parts].[TradeCodes]
(
    [TradeCodesID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PartID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Code] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [CodeTypeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SourceTypeID] [bigint] NULL,
    [RevisionID] [bigint] NULL,
    [ModifiedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Modifiedby] [int] NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [int] NULL,
    [PartLevel] [tinyint] NULL,
    [ZPLID] [int] NULL,
    [MappingDoneFlag] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MappingValueId] [int] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK__TradeCod__FEFAF27527F7A1C3] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TradeCodesID] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
    CONSTRAINT [UC_PartCode] 
        UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([PartID] ASC, [CodeTypeID] ASC, [PartLevel] ASC)
               WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                     IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                     ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE ExtractReports.dbo.TAllData
(
    PartID INT,
    Code VARCHAR(20),
    CodeTypeID INT,
    RevisionID BIGINT,
    ZPLID INT,
    ConCount INT,
    FeatureName NVARCHAR(500),
    FeatureValue NVARCHAR(500)
)
```

How to solve issue of slow on query above?

Comment: have you tried to add indexes to your quey combined for all on columns for example

Comment: Do you have any indexes on your tables? Also, why are you using `NOLOCK`? It's bad enough using it for a normal `SELECT`, but for an `INSERT`? That's, with respect, a *terrible* idea. It'll be a "magic make your data wrong" feature.

Comment: The execution plan you give inserts zero rows in 0 seconds. Post a plan that actually represents the problem

Comment: Your plan is not your *actual* execution plan. You haven't provided any info on `TradeCodesInsert` however you are filtering based on a join to this table; this could be a *not exists* since you're not using any data from this table - or preferably an *exists*. Remove the `nolock` hints.

Comment: I would expect the following indexes for this query: `TAllData (partid, codetypeid, code) INCLUDE (FeatureName, FeatureValue)` and `tradecodes (ZPLID, partlevel, PartID, CodeTypeID, Code) INCLUDE (RevisionID)` and `TradeCodesInsert (zplid, partlevel, partid, codetypeid)` Also the `LEFT JOIN` `IS NULL` is almost certainly better as a `NOT EXISTS`

Comment: sorry for late i don't have index on TAlldata table and have unique index on ( partid,codetype,partleve) on both of tables trade codes and trade code insert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create EXACTLY those indexs :

```
CREATE INDEX X1 ON [dbo].[TradeCodesInsert] (partid, codetypeid, partlevel);
CREATE INDEX X2 ON parts.tradecodes  (codetypeid, partlevel, zplid, partid) INCLUDE (RevisionID);
CREATE INDEX X2 ON ExtractReports.dbo.TAllData (code, codetypeid) INCLUDE (PartID , FeatureName, FeatureValue)
```

If you do not have it actually.